# Module not specified

Tags: android-studio, gradle

He abierto el proyecto y me daba error a la hora de sincronizar con Gradle, después de un rato, prácticamente solo dejó de dar ese problema pero ahora no me deja ejecutar la app porque no tiene módulo supuestamente. He probado todas las opciones que he encontrado para volver a restaurarlo pero ninguna ha funcionado. Por ejemplo: borrar la primera línea del Gradle y volver a sincronizar y pegarla de nuevos, resincroniar todo, File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart... Este es el Gradle y no sé qué más puede ser útil.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle(app)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única forma que conseguí que funcionase fue actualizando a la última versión del Android Studio y recuperando el proyecto de GitHub